# How can I make this addition method simpler?

Tags: python

This code adds a set of cards (in a game of blackjack)

```
# Rules
print("Dont enter Ace, Jack, Queen or king in the first 4 Inputs")
print("You will be told when to enter those")
print("if you dont have a card just enter 0")

# Line break
print("")

card1 = int(input("What is your first card: "))
card2 = int(input("What is your second card: "))
card3 = int(input("What is your third card: "))
card4 = int(input("What is your fourth card: "))


# Line break
print("")

# print("King = 10 \nJack = 10 \nQueen = 10 \nAce = 11 or 1 ")
AJKQ = (input("Any Ace, jack, Queens or kings: "))
AJKQ2 = (input("Any Ace, jack, Queens or kings: "))

# Line Break
print("")

print(card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + AJKQ + AJKQ2)
```

The code needs to add up the cards the user has and output them with Ace, jack queen and king

Im also not great with ifs and elifs, so whats the best way to compress this to smaller code?

Comment: If your code is working it's probably off-topic here. Try submitting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Why make your user press `Enter` so many darn times? `cards = input('Enter all of your cards, with spaces between them').split()` **No one** likes to have extended dialogues with computers.

Comment: @FMc - If the inputs are all numbers, pressing Enter instead of the spacebar might be easier, as there's an Enter key in the number pad on many keyboards.

Comment: Instead of line break use `\n` in previous print.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Nonsense. It's not about typing anyway. It's about reading endless prompts: "Enter your third card" ... "Enter your 99th card" ...

Comment: @Prajwal - Wouldn't that be kind of a long line? The way to dispense with multiple `print()` calls would be a triple-quoted string, I'd say.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 if you ask me the whole program looks childish. It is really doing nothing.

Comment: @Prajwal - It's blackjack, a common card game. I mean, this particular implementation isn't complete, but the plan is blackjack.

Comment: I added an answer. Check it out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("""Dont enter Ace, Jack, Queen or king in the first 4 Inputs
You will be told when to enter those.
if you dont have a card just enter 0\n""")

print(sum([int(input("what is your "+ char +" card: ")) for char in("first", "second", "third","fourth")]) +
sum([int(input("Any Ace, jack, Queens or kings: ")) for i in range(0,2)]))
```

this should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot,

Answer (score 0):

```
cards = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
card = []
for value in cards:
   card.append(int(input("What is your "+value+" card: ")))

...

print("".join(card) + AJKQ + AJKQ2)
```

Comment: While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.